# FontLoader and TextGeometry not getting imported properly in threejs

Tags: three.js

I am trying to add a 3D text over the BoxGeometry sides for front, right, left and top.

I implmented this code as below  :

```
loadFont = () =>{

const loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function ( response ) {

console.log("response "+response);

  return response;

} );}

   
createText = () => {

 let font = this.loadFont();

   this.textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( "Hello", {

    font: font,
    size: 70,
    height: 20,
    curveSegments: 4,
    bevelThickness: 2,
    bevelSize: 1.5,
    bevelEnabled: true

  });
  
  const materials = [
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, flatShading: true } ), // front
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } ) // side
  ];
  

  this.textMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(this.textGeo, materials );
  this.textMesh1.position.y = 80;
  this.textMesh1.position.z = 0;
  this.textMesh1.rotation.x = 0;
  this.textMesh1.rotation.y = Math.PI * 2;

  this.scene.add(this.textMesh1);
  this.root.add(this.textMesh1);
```

I am not able to receive a 3D text in my scene?
Getting Error - "THREE.TextGeometry: font parameter is not an instance of THREE.Font."

When I try using

```
      const loader = new FontLoader(); 
      this.textGeo = new TextGeometry( "Hello", {

    font: font,
    size: 70,
    height: 20,
    curveSegments: 4,
    bevelThickness: 2,
    bevelSize: 1.5,
    bevelEnabled: true

  });
```

I don't get exact place from where I am required to import these FontLoader and TextGeometry classes.

Any help, guidance or reference would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextGeometry` and `FontLoader` have been moved out of the core some time ago so you have to import them from `three/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry.js`  and `three/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js`.

Next, the following line of code does not work since `loadFont()` actually works asynchronous:

```js
let font = this.loadFont();
```

`loadFont()` will always return `undefined` since you return the font in the `onLoad()` callback function of `FontLoader.load()`. You have to rewrite your listing to account for the asynchronous nature of the code flow.

Comment: Thanks for helping.

I changed my code to async now : I am getting this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!' (at main.chunk.js:7258:24)" 

I don't find a way out for it ?

Comment: Consider to a new question for this runtime error. You probably want to demonstrate the issue with a live example though so it's easier to debug the issue.

Comment: Do you have an alternative to add a 3D text in the scene ?

Comment: Maybe modeling the text in Blender and load as glTF?